# ASP.NET Core RC2 Area not published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-areas, .net-core-rc2

So I just updated my app to use ASP.NET Core RC2. I published it using Visual Studio and noticed that my Area is not published:

This snapshot is from `src\MyProject\bin\Release\PublishOutput`:

[image]

And here is my Area, named `Admin` in Visual Studio:

[image]

Am I missing an step or what?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to configure your `publishOptions` section of `project.json` to include the `Areas` folder which is not included in the default template:

ex:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config",
    "Areas"
  ],
  "exclude": [ "bin" ]
}
```

**Update**

If you want to ensure that your controllers and other .cs files are not included, you can blacklist with the `exclude` property of `publishOptions` like so:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [ "wwwroot", "Views", "appsettings.json", "web.config", "Areas" ],
  "exclude": [ "**.user", "**.vspscc", "**.cs", "bin" ]
}
```

If you prefer more restrictive security, you can simply whitelist .cshtml files instead of including the entire Areas folder like so:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [ "wwwroot", "**.cshtml", "appsettings.json", "web.config" ],
  "exclude": [ "bin" ]
}
```

**Note**

Be careful using wildcards like `**.cshtml` as they will include all files in all subdirectories, including the `bin` directory.  If you have any views in your `bin` folder from a previous build, they will be duplicated again inside the new build output until the path becomes too long.

Comment: This indeed publishes the `Areas` folder BUT it also publishes the `Controllers` folder inside an area with `.cs` files! That's not wanted!

Comment: Updated my answer to include details of white-listing only cshtml files, rather than including the entire Areas folder

Comment: In order to include all Views folders which are located inside Areas folder, use this - Areas/**/Views, but it doesn't work in RC2 and 1.0 because of bug which is described here - https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3286, as workaround use this Areas/**/*.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Adding Areas will copy everything including the .cs files.

so should add `"Areas/**/Views/**/*.cshtml"` and `"Areas/ * /.cshtml"` under publish options instead of only `"Areas"`