# ASP.Net Core Nested Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I want to create area like the following structure

- Areas

  - Admin

    - FrontEnd

      - Controllers

        - HomeController.cs
      - Views
    - API

      - Controllers

        - HomeController.cs

Startup class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I already marked [Area("Admin/FrontEnd")] to HomeController but it doesn't work. It return the following error

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The view 'About' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/Admin/Views/Home/About.cshtml

How can I do?

Project

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535511/how-to-use-area-for-asp-net-core?rq=1

Comment: and of course https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/areas.html

Comment: Your screenshot have misspeled "FrontEnd" -> "ForntEnd".. it could be that

Comment: Already changed but still not work.  You provider link is not for nested area.  I found the link (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1595) that it mention ASP.net core doesn't support nested area.  is it really?

Comment: Ouch... Still you can do one thing.  Put Controllers wherever you want (they match by class name, not by namespace). Put Views wherever you want but on each method `return View("~/Full/Relative/Path/About.cshtml");
`

Comment: Specifying the exact path is more work, but it works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `AreaViewLocationFormats` on `RazorViewEngineOptions` to indicate what all paths you want MVC to look for views.

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Insert(0, "/Areas/{2}/FrontEnd/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Insert(0, "/Areas/{2}/FrontEnd/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
});
```

You can read the detailed documentation on what `AreaViewLocationFormats` is over here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorViewEngineOptions.cs#L92

Also you can just decorate your controllers to be just `[Area("Admin")]`