# User routes in the mvc core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

How can i make my user routes in mvc with core 2? Early, in just ASP.NET i used:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "index",
    "index",
    defaults: new
    {
        area = "AnoterArea",
        controller = "Base",
        action = "Index"
    });
```

But now what should i do? 
Im trying to do something like..

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapAreaRoute(
        "index",
        "Index",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        new 
        {
            controller ="Base",
            action = "Index"
        });
});
```

What do you say?

Comment: You should format your code properly so it's easy to read for others.

Comment: @Heri Can you say more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP MVC Core, you typically add those routes to the Startup.cs file. Inside the Configure() method, you should see something resembling this code:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");   
});
```

From there, you can add additional routes like this above the default route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
         //additional route
         routes.MapRoute(
            //route parameters    
        );

        //default route
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default",
          template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
         );   
});
```

In your case, you would want to add something like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "index",
  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Base}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
 );
```

Additionally, you will need to make sure that your Controller is within the Areas folder and the Controller action is decorated with the Area name:

```
[Area("AnotherArea")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Here is a link to a nice article about routing in .NET Core:

https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-routing-in-mvc/

Comment: Thank you)
And.. what if im needing in add another Area? Where i can write this?

Comment: Added example for adding new Area.

Comment: Looks simple) Thank you, again)

Comment: No problem. Here is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535511/how-to-use-an-area-in-asp-net-core)  explaining the full rundown on using Areas in ASP MVC Core if you want to know all the details.