# Asp.net core 2 Prefix Routing

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

How to create prefixed routing for MVC CRUD operation. I am working on an application that requires admin and front-end. For the admin I want all route to point to `localhost:5000/admin/....`

I have different Controllers

```
public class RoomsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Rooms        
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        return View(await _context.Rooms.ToListAsync());
    }

    //...
}
```

and

```
public class SlidersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public SlidersController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Sliders
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Sliders.ToListAsync());
    }

    //...
}
```

Now I want the admin route to be

```
localhost:5000/admin/rooms
localhost:5000/admin/slider
```

while other routes remain

```
localhost:5000/
localhost:5000/about
localhost:5000/...
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at areas - see [How to use an Area in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535511/how-to-use-an-area-in-asp-net-core#36535512)

Comment: What exactly is the point of that `admin/` prefix? Does this have any effect on the behavior of your routes?

Comment: I am trying to segment the admin side from the normal client area. So I decided to to for with @CalC option Area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the Problem by using MVC Area 
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas)

Comment: using Route to prefix is better answer;  that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use Attribute Routing for this. Till ASP.Net Web API we have the attribute named [RoutePrefix], but in ASP.Net Core 2 we can use [Route] attribute for the same purpose.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class DistrictController : ControllerBase
{

    [Route("{id:int:min(1)}")] // i.e. GET /api/District/GetDetails/10
    public IActionResult GetDetails(int id)
    {
    }

    // i.e. GET /api/District/GetPage/?id=10
    public IActionResult GetPage(int page)
    {
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{id:int:min(1)}")] // i.e. Delete /api/District/Delete/10
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/States/GetAllState")] // i.e. GET /api/States/GetAllState
    public IActionResult GetStates()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case it was as easy as replacing `RoutePrefix` with `Route`, did not have to change the string value, was picked up by Swagger just fine. I'm converting from .NET 4.5 to Core 6.0. Leaving it here for future visitors. Thanks!