# .NET Core UsePathBase() why original route still working?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For example the original route is `localhost:5000/Product`

When I use `app.UsePathBase("/admin")` will cause the route `localhost:5000/admin/Product` working.
But the original route `localhost:5000/Product` still working.

I expected it not enabled and I may use it for Front-end routing. How to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to existing answer.

- [@ISR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77991972/1814190) answer is not suitable for me because I want to use the original
  route for the front-end later.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62653853/1814190) described UsePathBase may be used for other
  purposes.
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47924759/1814190) try to use **Area** that will affect the folder
  structure.

So I decided to use the simple solution [Route("admin/[controller]")] It does not seem clever, but it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Use Middleware Extensions, but it is only recommended!
(You just may also have incorrect settings for your app.)

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>        {

        if (!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/admin")){   
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return;
        }


        await next();
    });
```