# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC : routing not working for area

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 questions, but they both relate to one key concept:  what do I need to add to Routing to handle pages inside an Area ?

1. I created an Area `Admin` in my ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC application. I would like to be able to visit the pages like this:

   ```
   a) /Admin/    ...to show the Index page
   b) /Admin/aa  ... show the view "aa"
   c) /Admin/bb  ... show the view "bb"
   ```

   The browser just returns a blank page. No errors or exceptions shown in the logs. I suspect the routing is incorrect.
2. I did add a new scaffolded item inside the `Admin` area (described above in question 1), and chose "MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework" for `Company`. After selecting the model, and other details, the VS2019 scaffolding generated the controller and the corresponding views (Create, Delete, Details, Edit, Index). But what routing code do I need to add to accommodate the newly generated URLs for `Company`?

Here is the routing code in the Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "AdminArea",
                    areaName: "Admin",
                    pattern: "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

Here is the controller in the folder `\Areas\Admin\Controllers`:

```
namespace MyWebSite.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public AdminController(ILogger<AdminController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("GET: Admin/Index/");
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult aa()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("GET: Admin/aa/");
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult bb()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("GET: Admin/bb/");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: reference link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535511/how-to-use-an-area-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

As the pattern setting in your startup.cs:

> pattern: "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

This means that your route must `start with Admin(area name)`, followed by the controller name and action name.

**The controller name in your current Admin area is also Admin**, so if you want to see the corresponding page, you should enter the link:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/Admin/Admin/
http://localhost:xxxx/Admin/Admin/aa
http://localhost:xxxx/Admin/Admin/bb
```

If you want to follow your ideal route, you need to set it up like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1#areas-for-controllers-with-views):

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute (
                   name: "AdminArea",
                   areaName: "Admin",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

But this will `ignore your Area name` and just display `http://localhost:xxxx/Controller/Action`.

If you create another controller named `HomeController` under Admin area, your path will become: `http://localhost:xxxx/Home/`

Here is the test result:

[image]