# How to convert Areas in .net to .net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am converting my asp.net project to asp.net core and have an issue with the conversion of areas component. I have done most of the conversion but cannot figure our to what the issue is with the rest. I need your assistance for this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Darío León answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59119066/12175349) if you are use endpoint pattern you should add routing pattern manually on startup.cs